# Importing my jar to spark shell

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I have a simple scala maven module which is part of a larger project (I created it as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-a-maven-module.html):

```
package com.myorg.simplr

import [...]

@SerialVersionUID(100L)
case class Simplr (){
    //class code
}
```

I am trying to use this class in spark shell, so I built a jar file "simplr-1.0.jar" and launched the spark shell with --jars simplr-1.0.jar.

Then, when I try to import, I get the following

```
scala> import com.myorg.simplr.Simplr
<console>:25: error: object myorg is not a member of package com
         import com.myorg.simplr.Simplr
                    ^
```

How can I make the import to work?

I used maven to build, and here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-parent-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>simplr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure some below points it will works
1. start spark shell like `./spark-shell --jars jar_path`
2. There is class file in jar under the same package which you import, open jar and check it.
3. After start spark go to http://localhost:4040/environment/ you jar will be in classpath entries or not.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Apparently, IntelliJ didn't automatically add a build section to the pom.xml and maven wasn't building anything.