# How to use createDataFrame and createDF on spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

There are good examples to use it, [as here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/manually-creating-spark-dataframes-b14dae906393), but on spark-shell *" ... createDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession"*.

PS: using Spark v2.2.

---

EDIT: sorry all, it is an external lib. Little change in the question: **how to import a Github lib in a Spark-shell session?**

Answer (score 2):

createDF() is not SparkSession method. It is spark-daria method. You need to install dependancy and import the spark-daria library them you should be able to use it.
Below article for your reference.

https://medium.com/@mrpowers/manually-creating-spark-dataframes-b14dae906393

---

> how to import a Github lib in a Spark-shell session?

You can use this alias with your appropriate "*etc*" in the `properties-file` value.

```
alias sshell_daria='export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2; spark-shell --packages mrpowers:spark-daria:0.35.0-s_2.11 --properties-file /opt/_etc_/_etc2_/conf/sparkShell.conf'
```

but, it  not work fine always, Spark-shell stop to work after this this messages

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/_etc_/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/_etc_/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.mrpowers#spark-daria added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
```

You can download the current version as *jar* file at [dl.bintray.com](http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/mrpowers/spark-dari), and [`--jars` option instead `packages`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863848/287948). So, the correct alias in this case is

```
alias sshell_daria='export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2; spark-shell --jars _your_path_/spark-daria-0.35.0-s_2.12.jar  --properties-file /opt/_etc_/_etc2_/conf/sparkShell.conf'
```

Comment: Hi @Manish! Thanks the post and sorry my mistake (it is a external library Daria)... Well, can you explain how to import https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria with Spark-shell?

Comment: Download spark-daria jar copy it the node. Assuming scala version is 2.11 spark-shell should started with below command
> spark-shell --packages mrpowers:spark-daria:0.35.0-s_2.11

Comment: Just FYI jar download link :
[link] http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/mrpowers/spark-daria/0.35.0-s_2.12/spark-daria-0.35.0-s_2.12.jar

Comment: Hi, after all, using `sshell_daria` and the example `val someDF = spark.createDF(...)`  of the illustration link, get  *"error: value createDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession"*

Comment: PS: to run `createDataFrame()` of the [illustration link](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/manually-creating-spark-dataframes-b14dae906393), I used `sshell_daria`  and `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. The error at `val someSchema` declaration  was *"error: not found: value StructField"*.